# Troubles downloading a pdf from PHP and getting it with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, pdf

I hope you're good!

I have an REST-API with PHP (Flight-PHP as framework) running in one server and I want to download a PDF saved in the server. But I'm having troubles with that.

The API resource that needs to be called to download the PDF is like:

```
GET /sales/:id/download
```

If I run the resource mentioned above in a browser, it will download a PDF file and it will display the PDF downloaded without troubles.

Now, in the frontend (a.k.a. a web application running in my browser) I have the following code:

```
$scope.download = (function (id) {
    $http.get($rootScope.api_url + 'sales/' + id + '/download')
    .then(function (response) {
        var resp = response.data;
        var blob = new Blob([resp], {type : 'application/pdf'});

        saveAs(blob, folio + ".pdf"); //yup, I'm using SaveAs.js
    }, function (reason) {
        alert("The file weren't downloaded");
    });
});
```

The code mentioned above downloads me a pdf file... But it is white!

So, after open both PDF's (one generated from the backend and another generated from the js script) it appears me with some chars I can't read (literally, I can't read)

[image: The file displayed in the left side is the downloaded by JS (the one that is NOT working); the right, the downloaded by the backend (the one that is working)]

So, my question is, how can I download the file using a different encode? And, which is the better way to encode this file to avoid the loss of chars?